# Moving from Ubuntu Netbook to Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I don't like the way of working with the 10.10 netbook and want to use desktop. I'm using Wubi and I'm new to ubuntu! Is there a way, simple switch between those two?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Desktop might already be installed, so start the application "Login Screen" (should be located under "System"), press unlock, enter password and choose "GNOME" (or Ubuntu Desktop) as default session.

If GNOME/Ubuntu Desktop is not available then you can install the package `ubuntu-desktop` (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) which will add the Ubuntu Desktop option to the GDM Session dropdown box at the bottom of GDM (Login Screen) and in the Login Screen area.

Comment: well done :) answer. if I can remember how to get xnest to start I'll add a screenshot for you.

Comment: additionally you may remove the package ubuntu-netbook and ubuntu-netbook-default-settings and any *netbook related packages.

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed the desktop version of Ubuntu 10.10 on my netbook. Runs like a charm.

If you want some netbook behaviour like maximized windows (Maximus) or power management (Jupiter), have a look at these great web sites for amazing tutorials and best software advice:

http://www.webupd8.org/
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/