# Do not like unity, asking for options

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an application to remove Unity UI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23165/is-there-an-application-to-remove-unity-ui)
>   [Will you have option to remove Unity in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9883/will-you-have-option-to-remove-unity-in-11-04)
>   [Will it be possible to use the actual Gnome UI once Ubuntu 11.04 will be available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10765/will-it-be-possible-to-use-the-actual-gnome-ui-once-ubuntu-11-04-will-be-availabl) 
>   [Moving from Ubuntu Netbook to Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21115/moving-from-ubuntu-netbook-to-ubuntu-desktop/)

Either one of these:

- I need an option to use desktop UI instead of Unity while installing Ubuntu Netbook 10.10.
- I need an application to remove Unity after the Ubuntu Netbook 10.10 is installed, without doing it manually.

Is there an easy way to do that? I did try manually but had problems. It is not a deal for experienced users like many of you here, but a big issue to a new one like me.

I hope those clever programmers of Unity not force me to use their UI.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, if you'd like Gnome on your netbook, you could technically install Ubuntu on it (no Netbook Edition).

If it's already there, you can just log out and choose the 'Gnome' session at the login screen. And maybe follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuNetbookEdition/ConvertGnomeSession) to make it fully customizable.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. Are saying that the only difference between the Netbook and the Desktop version is that for the Netbook Unity is used; that except the UI there is no difference. I tried using Netbook version since I thought it requires less resources. Thank You. DL.

Comment: Netbook Edition uses a different set of applications, so they are not the same thing.

Comment: I didn't say they were the same, I just gave you two alternative options. You should first try the Gnome session and see if it fits you. Then you an install a full Ubuntu, but maybe even better would be a lighter Ubuntu flavor like LUbuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu or XUbuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingXubuntu

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I will download the Desktop edition then. One last note for the Unity programmers, please do not reduce the sense of freedom of Ubuntu by not providing an easy option of not to use your UI. Happy programming. :) Thank you. DL.

Comment: Halo, I heard that the next Ubuntu 11.04 will be one edition only and will have Unity by default. I have no chance to try it. If you have tried the beta ver, do you have option not to use Unity? Thank you. DL.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I have got the answer. Sorry.